# Display multiple images from an array in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, image

I am a Laravel newbie and this is my problem. I have this piece of code below that works inside my controller.

```
public function home()
    return view('/home', [
    'image' => 'img/ctewzvv-aweadyojaae1cwbrvlo192.png',
    ]);
}
```

Inside my partial is this:

```
<div class="img-container">
     <a href="#">
          <img src="{{ asset( $image ) }}" alt="image">
     </a>
</div>
```

They work perfectly fine. My question is what if I have multiple image paths that I want to display inside a list like this:

```
public function home() {
     $images = ['img/ctewzvv-aweadyojaae1cwbrvlo192.png','img/abcwzvv-aweadyojaae1cwbrvlo192.png','img/vbfwzvv-aweadyojaae1cwbrvlo192.png'];
     return view('/home', [
         'images' => $images
     ]);
}
```

Would the above code possible?

Or what if I have all the images contained inside a folder, would it be possible if I display them at once? Thanks in advance. Help is much appreciated. Please respect.

Comment: Yes it is possible if you wrap your partial code with an `@foreach($images as $image)`

Comment: Hi @DestinatioN. That's interesting, I will try that out. How about if I just call all the images inside a folder like "*.jpg". Will this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can add a loop in your blade file and show all the images:

```
@foreach($images as $image)
    <img src="{{ asset( $image ) }}" alt="image">
@endforeach
```

Comment: I will try this my friend. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

you should try this:

```
public function home() {
     $images = ['img/ctewzvv-aweadyojaae1cwbrvlo192.png','img/abcwzvv-aweadyojaae1cwbrvlo192.png','img/vbfwzvv-aweadyojaae1cwbrvlo192.png'];
     return view('/home', [
         'images' => $images
     ]);
}
```

**View page:**

```
@foreach($images as $image)
<div class="img-container">
     <a href="#">
          <img src="{{ asset( $image ) }}" alt="image">
     </a>
</div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I'll definitely try this. Thanks @Saurabh

Comment: It works my friend. Then I put the @foreach inside the div. Many thanks.

Comment: @DaveMoreno: Glad to help :) and please accept my answer

Comment: I tried accepting the answer but I guess I can only pick one. I also tried hitting the button up for usefulness but it says below 15 reputation is just recorded. Anyways, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @DaveMoreno: Okay